# Combination with elements never in the same group more than once

Tags: r, algorithm, combinations, combinatorics

There is a group of `14` people. We want to set up a meeting schedule so that all `14` people meet together in groups of `3` (and one group of `2`) each week.

However, I do not want any two people in the same group more than once.

For example, if I have a group of `c(A,B,C)`, I do not want a subsequent group to be `c(A,B,D)`, because elements `A` and `B` are the same.

The output should be a list, with each element of the list representing a given week. Then within each list element (week) there should be lists of four groups of three people and one group of two people, with each person only appearing once, and between weeks no two persons should appear in the same group.

There are many possible solutions sets for this question. How many weeks we can meet before all combinations have been exhausted? How can I code this in `R`?

Comment: well, you have n elements in total, and you'll have n/3 groups of 3. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Yes, there is a reason for this. There was some context missing in the question which I have added.

Comment: oh right I get it now

Comment: It's an interesting question, but since it is mostly a combinatorics problem (once you know the mathematical formula it should be rather trivial to implement it) it may be better suited for [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I disagree with @jdehesa. It's an interesting question.

Comment: @italo I literally said I _do_ think it is an interesting question. That doesn't change the fact that it may be better suited for (as in, "it may find more and better answers, in addition to be more on-topic, in") Mathematics SE. You can obviously think differently, but I didn't dispute the interest/validity of the question.

Comment: @jdehesa sorry for not elaborating. I was worried the question was going to get deleted and I'm trying to solve it in R. My comment should be: It's an interesting question for me as an R programmer.

Answer (score 1):

```
elements <- c('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N')
allcomb <- t(combn(elements, 3)) #Returns 364 different combinations
```

It is possible to filter the ones that have 2 similar letters. However, the answer changes depending on which subgroup you start comparing with. I'm doing it sequentially.(Starting with `A,B,C`)

```
for (a in 1:28){
  l <- vector("list", nrow(allcomb))
  for (b in 1:nrow(allcomb)){
    l[[b]] <- sum(allcomb[a,] %in% allcomb[b,])!=2
    }
  allcomb <- allcomb[unlist(l),]
}
```

Got 28 after trial and error.

```
> allcomb
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,] "A"  "B"  "C" 
 [2,] "A"  "D"  "E" 
 [3,] "A"  "F"  "G" 
 [4,] "A"  "H"  "I" 
 [5,] "A"  "J"  "K" 
 [6,] "A"  "L"  "M" 
 [7,] "B"  "D"  "F" 
 [8,] "B"  "E"  "G" 
 [9,] "B"  "H"  "J" 
[10,] "B"  "I"  "K" 
[11,] "B"  "L"  "N" 
[12,] "C"  "D"  "G" 
[13,] "C"  "E"  "F" 
[14,] "C"  "H"  "K" 
[15,] "C"  "I"  "J" 
[16,] "C"  "M"  "N" 
[17,] "D"  "H"  "L" 
[18,] "D"  "I"  "M" 
[19,] "D"  "J"  "N" 
[20,] "E"  "H"  "M" 
[21,] "E"  "I"  "L" 
[22,] "E"  "K"  "N" 
[23,] "F"  "H"  "N" 
[24,] "F"  "J"  "L" 
[25,] "F"  "K"  "M" 
[26,] "G"  "I"  "N" 
[27,] "G"  "J"  "M" 
[28,] "G"  "K"  "L"
```

Comment: I up-voted because this answer is getting close. However, the output should be a list, with each element of the list representing a given week. Then within each list element (week) there should be lists of four groups of three people and one group of two people. Within each week, each person should only appear once, and between weeks no two persons should appear in the same group.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm here's a lower bound:

On average each person expects to meets (4*3 + 1*2)/5 = 2.8 people per week

Each person needs to meet 13 people.

13/2.8 = 4.64 weeks.
So the answer should be 5 weeks.